# Sliding vertical menu : prevent the title from moving left on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to fix an issue with a sliding vertical menu where the menu header moves right when I'm over it.

You can see it yourself [here](http://www.domenicoconte.it) when going over `portfolio`.

This is the CSS I'm currently using :

```
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    right: 20px;
    height: 80%;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: default;
    letter-spacing:8px;
}

#menu li {
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}

#menu-portfolio {
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid; 
    padding-right: 0.3em;
    font-size: 95%;
}

.menu-gallery-selector {
    font-size: 85%;
    text-align:left;
    margin:5%;
}

.menu-gallery-selector:nth-of-type(1) {
    margin-top:15%;
}

#menu-contact {
    float: left;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    padding-left: 0.4em;
    font-size: 95%;
}
```

And this is the javascript :

```
$("#menu-portfolio").bind("mouseover", expand);
$("#menu-portfolio").bind("mouseout",collapse);
$(".menu-gallery-selector").hide();


function collapse() {
    $(".menu-gallery-selector").hide();
}

function expand() {
    $(".menu-gallery-selector").show();
}
```

Comment: what browser do you use? I see no problem
And I'd also consider making this menu without any javascript, you can use `:hover` pseudo class to show/hide submenus with this simple 2 rules
`li:hover ul{display: none} li:hover ul{display: block;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple fix

```
#menu-portfolio {
text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by adding `text-align: right;` to the

```
#menu-portfolio {
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
    padding-right: 0.3em;
    font-size: 95%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Should do the work

Answer (score 1):

When I test this the "Portfolio" text moves left not right. The reason the "Portfolio" text moves is because the text of the widest list item "Automotive" expands the width of the `<ul>` tag which contains the "Portfolio" text. You need to put `text-align: right;` on the Portfolio text.